# What expression to use to capture middle part of a string

Tags: vba

Beginner here. 2nd day into VB.

How do I capture the middle part of the string below? What method (Split, Contains, Trim, eg) to use?

Variable string message1:

> "background:url(//test.image.com/bao/uploaded/i2/1951211594/TB2m1gjzYlmpuFjSZFl>XXbdQXXa_!!1951211594.jpg_40x40q90.jpg)"

To become:

> //test.image.com/bao/uploaded/i2/1951211594/TB2m1gjzYlmpuFjSZFlXXbdQXXa_!!19512>11594.jpg

Comment: What have you tried?  Show examples of your effort and say why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string will always contain `"background:url(` in the beginning and `)"` at the end, you can just use `Mid$(message1, 17, Len(message1) - 18)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s

s = Split(strMessage, ":url(")(1)
s = Left(s, Len(s)-2)
```